# How to first predict category then do regression based on which category it is predicted?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, classification

How to first predict category then do regression based on which category it is predicted? Basically I have data that are't really that continuously distributed on its range, so it would be good if I can have some coarse predictions over which region the label likely to fall into and then do a more detailed regression to predict where exactly does the label equal to in that region.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Would you be able to include a plot that illustrates what you describe?